# Using jedis with spring, but not with spring-data lib, where to store pool?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

In the jedis docs it says to create a pool:

JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost");

And that I should be storing this statically somewhere.

I know spring has a spring-data library that is in development, but I just want to use the library w/o that for now.

Where do you suggest I create this static reference to the pool?

Should I create a JedisService and then have a public method that returns this pool?

Do I do this using the singleton pattern? lock before returning?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring, you can't use `new` and have the object under Spring's control.  Make it a Spring bean and initialize it using a factory method.

You declare beans in your Spring application context XML (or using annotations, if you're so inclined):

```
<bean id="jedisPool" class="foo.bar.JedisPool">
    <constructor-arg ref="jedisPoolCofig"/>
    <constructor-arg value="localhost"/
</bean>
```

Comment: any tips on how to define a bean and make it static? any code would be appreciate as I'm not to familiar with this.

Comment: but that doesn't make it static does it?

Comment: Beans aren't static - why do you think so?

Comment: No what I am saying is, how do I make the reference to the jedisPool static?  The Jedis wiki says to make the reference to jedisPool static.

Comment: Why must it be static?  The example in your question calls "new"; that's not static.

Comment: sorry for the confusion: "You can store the pool somewhere statically, it is thread-safe." https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started